# Can someone explain the statsmodels code question for me?

Tags: python, dataset, statsmodels

I am curious that the following codes are related to US economic data.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.datasets.macrodata.load_pandas().data
```

Can someone explain the function datasets and macrodata for me? I did not find it in the official guide of statsmodels.

Comment: This is just a package. See it as a directory to classify the data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that that is United States Macroeconomic data

Description: US Macroeconomic Data for 1959Q1 - 2009Q3

See:
http://www.statsmodels.org/0.6.1/datasets/generated/macrodata.html